# Происхождение слова "то бишь"

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Интересно узнать ваше мнение о происхождении и значении слова "то бишь".

Answer (score 3):

ТО БИШЬ - пояснительный просторечный союз со значением ТО ЕСТЬ, А ИМЕННО, ВЕРНЕЕ. Например:  "Третьего дня, то бишь на той неделе, сказываю я старосте... "

БИШЬ, частица (прост.). Обозначает припоминание. Как б. его зовут? О чем б. сейчас я говорил?

БИШЬ - исконное слово, скороговорка от БАИШЬ - говоришь (от  "баять" в русском языке образованы слова байка, обаятельный).

ТО БИШЬ  пишется раздельно, но в словаре Ушакова зафиксировано дефисное написание, которое впоследствии было изменено.